# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when encoding data in UserDefaults (Swift)

Tags: swift

[image] Hi, I am trying to save data in Userdefaults but whenever I run this page of the app I am getting Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOC) as shown in the image.

Prior to this, I was getting the same exact error on the line beneath the one that I am getting it on right now, but now it is coming on this current line as seen in the image. How can I fix this to save my data every time the app launches?

```
var highScore = 0
var bronzeStatus = 0
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    highScore = defaults.value(forKey: "Add1High") as! NSInteger!
    bronzeStatus = defaults.value(forKey: "bronzeMed") as! NSInteger!
```

Underneath:

```
        if correctNumber > highScore {
            highScore = correctNumber
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.setValue(highScore, forKey: "Add1High")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }


        if highScore >= 15 {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let bronzeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New Medal!", message: "You earned a bronze medal!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            bronzeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(scoreAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        bronzeStatus = 1
        defaults.setValue(bronzeStatus, forKey: "bronzeMed")
        defaults.synchronize()
        }
```

Comment: can you show the code, which you are using to store the value in userDefaults

Comment: **Never** use `valueForKey` with `UserDefaults`. There are convenience methods for scalar types `integer(forKey:`, `bool(forKey:`,  `double(forKey:`. And for objects it's `object(forKey:` And don't use `NSInteger` in Swift at all. Use native Swift `Int` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
highScore =  defaults.integer(forKey: "Add1High")
```

it converts the returned value to an NSInteger. If the value is an NSNumber, the result of -integerValue will be returned. If the value is an NSString, it will be converted to NSInteger if possible. If the value is absent or can't be converted to an integer, 0 will be returned. So no need to convert on your part.

Also while setting use

```
defaults.set(highScore, forKey: "Add1High")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 code**

> this code work parfect..

```
 var highScore = 0
 var bronzeStatus = 0
```

> ViewDidLoad:

```
        //set integer type data
        UserDefaults.standard.set(20, forKey: "Add1High")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(30, forKey: "bronzeMed")

        //Get integer type data
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        highScore = defaults.integer(forKey: "Add1High")
        bronzeStatus = defaults.integer(forKey: "bronzeMed")

        print("\(highScore)\(bronzeStatus)") //2030
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to check your userdefaults value exits or not

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if defaults.value(forKey: "Add1High") != nil{

      highScore = defaults.value(forKey: "Add1High") as! NSInteger!

    }


    if defaults.value(forKey: "bronzeStatus") != nil{

      bronzeStatus = defaults.value(forKey: "bronzeStatus") as! NSInteger!

    }
```

Because you have condition
       if correctNumber > highScore{}

so this part may execute or maybe not ,so you have to check for that